# CRC or MD5 Calculation for file certification

Tags: c#, certificate, md5, crc

I have to certify my files.
To do that I use this:

```
public static string CalculateFileCrc(string strFilename)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(strFilename))
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            string strResult = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToUpperInvariant();
            return strResult;
        }
    }
}
```

that produces something like:

> 8CA7F85DC22A1DEB0917707B6534F480

which to me is perfect for here that takes into account:

- complete filename including path
- file content

my first question is: is there a correct and safe way to store into the result also the datetime of the file so that if changed it produces a different result?

Second: I have been asked to condense that number in a shorter (4 hex chars) form which is easier to be reported by hand. Something like

> B2A3

but always keeping the same degree of certification as above.
People here have as an example a program (for robot handling) that certifies a program in that way.

Thanks for helping

Patrick

---EDIT---
I have also tried this:

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(strFilename))
    {
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(md5.ComputeHash(stream));
    }
}
```

Comment: "always keeping the same degree of certification" - what does that mean?

Comment: To me that would mean to store in that number: 1. filename 2. file content 3. file last modification datetime

Comment: You can generate md5 from file stream, the add filename as string and modification date, and calculate md5 once more?

Comment: Yes that would do but how to condense it in a 4 char string?

Comment: And what is the purpose of that value you calculate, what are going to do with it? I mean 4 char hex string is not very "unique" (md5 hash is also not "unique" is strict sense, but 4 char hex string can only have about 65K different values, so collisions will be very frequent).

Comment: MD5 is a 32 byte array, if you want to convert it to 4 byte array, you will loose the unique code of md5

Comment: The purpose is to produce a certified file and write the MD5 (or similar) to a report signed by the customer. If he modifies it we will notice for the MD5 (or similar) is changed

Comment: Well if that is important (like money are involved, or you don't want malicious user to change that file without you noticing) - 4 char hex string is not enough, so you have to convince whoever is in charge to increase that length. But if you don't care - just do `Substring(0,4)` on your md5 hash.

Comment: I think that concludes the issue. Thanks

Comment: You are not including the file path in the MD5 with the posted code. You would want to compute the MD5 first on the path, then some representation of the modification date and time, and then the data. The routine should not have "Crc" in the name, since there is no CRC here anywhere. Converting to upper case just throws away information needlessly -- you need to have a good reason to do that. As already noted, 16 bits offers very little in the way of "certification".